# How to start a process in perl with with a command-line argument?

Tags: perl, command-line

Is there a way to initiate an nmap scan based off a symbol?  I want to be able to run a nmap scan
when i execute my code at the terminal something like this: script.pl -b xx.xxx.xxx.  I tried using an if statement to do this but it's working.  Does anyone know hpw to do this properly?

```
if("-b")
{
('nmap -v -r ARGS[0] >>file.txt')
}
```

Comment: Did "symbol" become some sort of code word for "command-line argument"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a single letter as a flag **Getopt::Std** is all you need.

```
use Getopt::Std;

my %opt;
getopt("b",\%opt);

system "nmap -v -r $opt{b} >> file.txt" if exists $opt{b};
```

getopt takes a string of the letters used as flags and maps them and their values to a hash table. getopt("ab",%opt) would set %opt to something like ( a => "foo", b => "bar" ) provided a and b are both actually used when the script is called.

Answer (score 5):

Command line option parsing is made easy by using perl's **Getopt::Long** module. Here is an example:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my ($b);

my $result = GetOptions ("b=s" => \$b);

if ($b) {
    system ('nmap -v -r ' . $b . ' >>file.txt');
}
```

the **b=s** inside **GetOptions** gets a string argument from **-b**, and sets it to the **$b** variable.